# Windbg getting the size of a C++ object

Tags: c++, windbg

Doing some analysis of an Internet Explorer crash. (The aurora exploit). Say I have a vftable of an object at 01e2fe80. I know the object is a mshtml!CImgElement. How would I find the size of this object? How would I find that the object mshtml!CImgElement is x bytes big?

```
     bp mshtml!CEventObj::GenericGetElement+0x93 ".printf \"esi = [%08x] \",esi;dds poi(esi) l1;gc"

     esi = [01e2fe80] 01e2fcd0  7dc59478 mshtml!CImgElement::`vftable'
```

Reference:

http://dreamofareverseengineer.blogspot.de/2011/10/reversing-aurora-vulnerability-cve-2010.html

Comment: You could guess using the heap extension by dumping the heap block occupied:
`!heap -p -a 01e2fcd0` and examining the **UserSize** attirbute

Answer (score 0):

[Operators in C++ Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `sizeof(type)` return size of data type, but probably `CImgElement` contain private data and to display the size required private information (private symbols) which there is no for mshtml module.

```
0:021> ?? sizeof(MSHTML!CImgElement)
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
***                                                                   ***
***    In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path   ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: MSHTML!CImgElement                            ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
Couldn't resolve error at 'MSHTML!CImgElement)'
```